# Count of Unique Records with criteria from other Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

Good Day,

I have a schedule people populate where they are on tasks. There is a due date and date completed. Some of these tasks are there multiple times as they are done over several days. I'm trying to use  a combination of COUNT, UNIQUE and FILTER to get the count. There is just something off in this formula that is giving me a odd result.

Column L is a copy of all tasks (ME Close Checklist Column A with a date greater than 1 (calculated in the same worksheet column K)

M2 is the expected value by apply UNIQUE to this list. (57)

K2 are the count of values great that 1 (62)

In I2 I'm trying
=COUNT(--(LEN(UNIQUE(FILTER('ME Close Checklist'!A7:A333,'ME Close Checklist'!K7:K333>0,"")))>0))

but its giving me a number greater that 62.

I know that there 205 unique records the checklist column A via =COUNT(UNIQUE('ME Close Checklist'!A7:A333))

[image]

Small Example

[image]

In this example there are 5 items overdue (column K greater >0), but in column A 48 and 63 are listed twice so the count I would be looking for is 3. (unique records from column A where the related value in K is greater than 0)

Please provide some suggestions.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: It would be helpful to see a small sample date and the expected result for that sample.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, please see the update.